# Meaning of "すわりがいい"?

Tags: words, meaning

In a book about introductory Mandarin Chinese written in Japanese, one of the first sections lists some special characteristics of Mandarin not familiar to Japanese speakers (e.g. usually only one reading of kanji, no distinctive male/female language, etc). One of the sections is written below:

> ２字熟語
>
> ２音節、つまり２字熟語が多いというのが中国語の特徴です。２音節は音のすわりがいいと好まれる傾向があるのです。

The first sentence seems to be saying that words in Mandarin are commonly formed from two syllables, and thus two kanji (what is strange is that it's mentioned, since two-kanji words are common in Japanese too). The second sentence's "すわりがいい" is preventing me from figuring out the meaning, though.

TL;DR: what does "すわりがいい" mean?

Comment: See #2 in http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/120691/m0u/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A/

Comment: Interesting - I'll ask the same question I asked below though, how can syllable sounds have a sense of 落ちつきぐあい or 安定?

Comment: Normally you can think of すわりがいい as 'fitting well', does this make more sense for you?

Comment: Took a Mandarin dic. file, took all 2-character compounds (total: 24,558) and counted how often a syllable appeared in 1st/2nd place. The most common syllables in 2nd place (ratio 2nd/1st=5..26): de5, zhe5, zhe3, qi5, tui3, nan4, ran2, se4, kuan3, liao4, ceng2, lang3. If I weigh each syllable by the frequency of the words for which they are used, the most common ones are: zhe3, qie3, xie1, ge5, gei3, gai1, zhe5, zei2, run4, liao4, zai3, liang4, zhai2, tui3. 
Also there are some that appear only in the second place: zi5(275), shi5(36), tou5(33), fu5(21), and 200+ more appearing only 1-5 times.

Comment: @Hikonyan Just like in English there are lots of words that have multiple meanings.  This can either be just a coincidence or because these meanings are related.  In this case, I don't know the actual etymology, but my guess that すわり had the connotation of "settle" or "rest," so meaning #2 is natural.

Comment: By the way, it sometimes happens that the same syllables can mean entirely opposite things.  This is typically due to a coincidence of kanji pronounciations.  For example 私立大学 and 市立大学, both pronounced しりつだいがく mean, respectively, private univerity and public university.  However, that's not the only way, just like "bad" in English can sometimes mean "good."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「２[音節]{おんせつ}は[音]{おと}のすわりがいいと[好]{この}まれる[傾向]{けいこう}があるのです。」

「すわりがいい」 can mean a few different things and in this case, it is important to treat it in pair with 「**音の**」.  It is not about any other kind of すわり that the author is talking about.

「音のすわりがいい」 would mean "**aurally pleasing or agreeable**" in my own words.

> "Two-syllable words tend to be preferred (in Chinese) as they are aurally pleasing."

「すわりがいい」 is more often used to describe the physical (or spatial) stability of an object and that would probably be what you get from the dictionary.  Here, the usage is a little different.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it means something like 違和感や不快感がなく自然なさま in this case.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the core meaning here then, but how can two syllables put together have a sense of 違和感 or 快感, if that is how すわりがいい is to be interpreted?

Comment: Well I think what's going on here is it's saying that two syllables are the preferred sound because it sounds natural. Since according to the sentence these two syllable words are a characteristic of the Chinese language.

This is what makes sense to me anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, but preferably I can get one more opinion since you are not totally sure